# PHP set and get multi-dimentional array values

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have a PHP class as follows:

```
Class ArrayStore{

static $storage = array();

public static set($key, $value){
  //set value
}

public static get($key){
  //return value
}

}
```

How I want to use:

```
ArrayStore::set('["id"]["name"]["last"]', 'php');
ArrayStore::get('["id"]["name"]["last"]'); //should return php

ArrayStore::set('["multi"]["array"]', 'works');
ArrayStore::get('["multi"]["array"]'); //should return works
```

Let me know if there is a better way of setting and getting a multidimensional array with reason.

Edit:
I tried something like this:

```
<?php
$x = array(1=>'a');
$op="\$x"."[1]";
$value=eval("return ($op);");

echo $value;//prints a.
?>
```

Comment: The code you posted is not OOP but procedural programming (with global variables) under disguise. PHP already provides the [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class that works as an array. Use it!

Answer (score 0):

From your logic you can do like this:

```
<?php
class ArrayStore{

static $storage = array();

public static function  set($key, $value){
  self::$storage[$key] = $value;
}

public static function  get($key){
  return self::$storage[$key];
}

}
ArrayStore::set('["id"]["name"]["last"]', 'php');
echo ArrayStore::get('["id"]["name"]["last"]'); //should return php
echo "<br>";
ArrayStore::set('["multi"]["array"]', 'works');
echo ArrayStore::get('["multi"]["array"]'); //should return works
```

Comment: It returns the expected output. However, It is not storing the data like 
`array('id' => array('name'=>array('last' => 'php')))`